# Function declaration as var instead of function

Tags: javascript, functions

More and more I'm seeing functions being declared like

```
var foo = function() {

    // things
};
```

Instead of how I had learned, like

```
function foo() {

    // things
}
```

What's the difference? Better performance? Scope? Should I be using this method?

Comment: it's worth noting that in javascript, functions are [first-class-citizens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function). This allows you to pass around behavior just like objects. This is very useful for callbacks and delegation, among other things.

Comment: *Scope*. The variable name wrapping "//things" is essentially/hopefully preventing name collisions of the "//things" it's wrapping, with other JavaScript (files) included. Another way to think of it is that you have created a namespace "foo".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`var foo = function() {}`  defines a variable that references an anonymous function.

`function foo() {}` defines a named function `foo`.

Either can be passed by name as function parameters and either can be instantiated if the intended use is for OOP.

At the end of the day, which one you use is largely dictated by your specific use-case (Javascript is fun like that ;)). If you end up using the former, I would *strongly* suggest that you name the function:

`var foo = function MY_function() {}`. This naming convention helps your debugger callstack not be useless.

Comment: Got a goof there on function() MY...

Comment: @Demian Brecht, and what about var foo = function foo() {...} approach?

Comment: @shabunc: What about it? It's listed in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @Demian Brecht, no, actually in last paragraph variable is called `foo` and function is called `MY_function`

Comment: @shabunc: The name doesn't matter. What matters is the value in the callstack. As an example, [NAMESPACE]_[fn name] is the convention used by Mozilla. The name itself doesn't matter as long as your convention is consistent throughout your project.

Answer (score 13):

function expression:

```
//someFunction(); //wouldn't work when uncommented
var someFunction = function(){ alert('yay'); };
```

The func expression in this case is anonymous but assigned to a var for reference. This is different from a labeled function statement in the following ways:

- it can't be hoisted (called before it's defined)
- `new someFunction().constructor.name === 'someFunction';//false` instances don't get the var name for constructor.name because a reference to the function is assigned to the var but the var, not the function, is tied to the var name

In a labeled function statement:

```
//someFunction(); //works when uncommented
function someFunction(){ alert('yay'); }
```

- hoisting works
- `new someFunction().constructor.name === 'someFunction'; //true` the name is tied directly to the function.

Generally speaking there's not really any great reason to do expression to var unless you want calls to fail if things get moved around or you're defining/assigning a method in one line. I actually find hoisting useful for organizing objects with internal func and method definitions at the bottom so I can get to the actual behavior of the object and do one-line public method definitions (by just assigning funcs to `this.` with the same name) all in one spot for ease of reference. You should always try to use labeled statements for constructors, IMO, so you can identify an object's 'type' via its constructor.

Answer (score 8):

Your first example is an **expression** while the second example is a **statement**.  Defining functions as expressions allows for more flexibility in where the definition can occur, what you can assign it to, that you can pass it as a parameter, etc...

For example:

```
SomeThing('abc', function(a,b) {return a*b;});
```

vs...

```
function tmp(a,b) { 
    return a*b;
}

SomeThing('abc', tmp);
```

More complex examples would become obcenely complicated without the function expression syntax.

Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 4):

The main practical difference is hoisting. For example:

```
foo(); // alerts 'hello'
function foo() {alert('hello');}
```

vs

```
foo(); // throws an error since foo is undefined
var foo = function() {alert('hello');}
```

Also, this is undefined behavior

```
function foo(){
  if (true) {
    function bar(){}
  }
  bar();
}
```

while this is ok.

```
function foo(){
  if (true) {
    var bar = function(){}
  }
  bar();
}
```

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with defining a function inside a function in JS. There's not many places you can't define a function in JS.

Comment: @ErikReppen You definitely can't use a function declarations within non-function blocks (like within an if statement). I can't seem to find where I read they can't be used within another function.

Comment: @Austin There's nothing wrong with a function definition within an `if` statement either!

Comment: @Austin: Perhaps you read it at w3schools? ;)

Comment: I think you may have been reading about a different language. JS has first-class functions (so they can be defined and passed around just like any other object or var). Scope is functional rather than block-based so blocks don't typically change what you can or can't do in a given scope/object-context in any way that I can think of so blocks are a bit more loose in JS. Just defining a var in an if statement that doesn't execute, for instance, will still make that var name available as a local var (but without a value set).

Comment: @ErikReppen Function expressions can be used anywhere. Function declarations can't be. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069204/function-declarations-inside-if-else-statements

Comment: They can still both be used anywhere but that's an example of where function hoisting gets weird in a block of if statements. The point is that assigned anonymous funcs are preferable in cases where you're defining a like-named function differently based on multiple tests.